# Eclipse 2020-06 throws errors on valid !Ref and !Sub in CloudFormation (YAML) templates

Tags: eclipse, yaml, aws-cloudformation

The `!Ref` and `!Sub` are "bread and butter" of CloudFormation YML templates.

When I upgraded from Eclipse 2019-xx to 2020-06, I started getting these errors:
[image]

These are valid templates successfully and repeatably deployed.

Is there a way to either get proper validation, or turn it off?

I tried disabling validation through the Project properties but there is no option for YAML.

Comment: Are you using the [aws toolkit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/tke-cfn-editor.html) for eclipse?

Comment: That the "Type" column says "Language Servers" makes me think you're using Wild Web Developer's YAML support. Do these only show up when you have the file open in an editor? Which download of 2020-06 is this, and was there already support for editing YAML in your 2019-xx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error comes from the Visual Studio Code YAML language server which is included in [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) which became part of some IDE packages in the 2020-06 release.

You can get rid of the error by switching off the YAML language server as follows (which reduces the support for YAML files to syntax highlighting only):

1. In *Window > **Preferences: Language Server*** **uncheck** ***YAML*** and click *Apply and Close*
2. In the *Problems* view **delete the error**

The Visual Studio Code YAML language server has schema support. So there might be a better solution without turning off the language server completely.

Comment: Has someone reported this to the Wild Web Developer team? Surely this is a very common problem. It's yet one more reason (the reasons are accumulating rapidly!) for ditching Eclipse and using VS Code. If they don't know about it, they can't address it. I'll be happy to file a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to trying another editor, [CloudFormation's Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint) should handle [these functions and more](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code/blob/089b197e2c7df4ec26d35c23ebb77383c724a86e/client/src/extension.ts#L57) in addition to autocompletion, documentation links on hover, inline [linting](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/), and [template resource dependency graph previews](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code/pull/106). Got an [online demo](https://github.com/PatMyron/cfn-lint-online) if you have a Github account and want to check it out quickly before installing

Comment: About which editor are you talking? This error is shown in the Eclipse IDE and it comes from the Visual Studio Code YAML language server. Are you so open and have you tried it with Eclipse? Please note, when someone has a question about a tool, most people see the recommendation of a tool as SPAM. Please also note, that asking to recommend a tool is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you as the author of the language server you are promoting are open to support other editors and IDEs instead of a single editor only, check out how [Eclipse LemMinX](https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx#clients) does it.